Prevent NavigationLink to go back by itself to Navigation View
I have a list of restaurants that its observed all the time:
func getAllRestaurantsInParameters(lat: Double, long: Double){
        
        self.repo.getAllRestaurants().watch(block: {restaurants in
            
            self.restaurantList = (restaurants as! [Restaurant])
        })
}

In my main view, I have a NavigationView that has a list of NavigationLinks:
NavigationView{
            
     List{
         ForEach(restaurantList, id: \.self) { restaurant in
                             
                NavigationLink(destination: IndividualRestaurantView()){

                      ZStack {Text(restaurant.name)}
                }
         }
     } 
}

Whenever I enter whatever Navigaiton Link restaurant, and change something to another restaurant, the navigation link will go back by itself to the first main view.. Why that happens? I assume its because the observer method, that changes the restaurantList whenever a change happens, but still I dont want to go back to the main view..
How can I prevent this?
I did test to add .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
.navigationViewStyle(.stack) at the NavigationView, but did not work.
Any other options?
The .watch(block: will observe any change of the restaurants and call that method.
How can I prevent the navigation link to go back to the navigation view by itself?

Please show how Restaurant is declared. You should not use \.self as the id if properties of the restaurants can change. You should use something that cannot change throughout the "lifetime" of a restaurant.

Can you use NavigationStack instead of NavigationView?

Also, do you need to support iOS versions earlier than 16? If not, you should use NavigationStack.

@Sweeper, you mean that I need to use something like\.self.name? or .\self.getID(). What is the difference between using the entire object? Because not the object that I am in (inside the navigation link) its changing, but the other object.
In this case if I am in restaurant A, and restaurant B gets changed, the view will still get pushed back by itself

@Chris, I need to stay in iOS 15 unfortunately, cant use NavigationStack
